# ffnet: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python

If I execute this code:

```
conec = mlgraph((10, 30, 1), biases=True)
net = ffnet(conec)
net.train_tnc(input, output, maxfun = 10000, messages = 1)
```

where `input` is a matrix of 1000x10 and `output` is a matrix of 1000x1 both complete fill in with float numbers. I cannot understand why this answer:

```
if max(col) == min(col):
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`
```

I think this has nothing to do with boolean values. So what can be?

Comment: I don't think so; I'm not using boolean arrays... There are float matrix and array.

Comment: At the end I found the problem. It was just to change the type of input and output tables: from `numpy.asmatrix` to `numpy.asarray`.